# POST request status code (500) when using the request module in node.js. POST request in Postman is working fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, request, postman

I'm trying to do a post request to an external server using the Request - Simplified HTTP client in node.js. I expect to get the departure times of a specific bus station. But everytime I get a bad response from the server (status code 500). The code I'm using is listed below:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
url: 'http://www.wsw-mobil.de/app-panel.php',
qs: { p: 'wuppertal', s: 'Blankstrasse' },
headers: 
{ 'Postman-Token': 'd67fca9f-1296-1aa6-0aef-0451a16d6033',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(body);
});
```

As you can see I'm using the code generated by Postman. 
The weird thing now: If I'm doing the post request in Postman straight away I'm getting a successful response (200). You can see all the options and the successful response in the image below:

[POST request in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvqAH.png)

I'm trying to get my head around this problem for several hours. Does anyone have a glue why I'm getting a bad response (500) in node.js using the request module?

Comment: Silly question but do you have node installed? How are you running that generated code? What are you POSTing?

Comment: Also, do you *Need* those headers? At least one is from Postman and it has nothing to do with that endpoint.

Comment: Yes, node.js is installed. Also, I tried to do some requests without headers or just only the 'Content-Type'  pair . But I get the same bad responses (status code 500). In Postman all the POST requests are working and I recieve the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the code and get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'request'
```

To me, it seems like you need to add a `package.json` file in the same dir as you have your code and then `npm install request --save` this should then bring in that module and allow you to send the request.

**UPDATE**:
Having installed the module - I see the error coming back from the POST request.

After some trail and error the following combination of `headers`, seem to return a `200 OK` and a list of results.

```
headers: {  'accept': '*/*',
            'user-agent':'*' }
```

Not too sure what's happening with that endpoint to cause the original issue.

Comment: Thanks, Danny. But the request module is correctly installed. I'm also do some GET request using the api's from external websites like darksky to get weather information and the repsonses are all successful.

Comment: My mistake - Once I installed and ran again, I saw the 500 error. It's quite generic and doesn't get much info.

Comment: @TheGrabbi I managed to get a good response back by adding the `user-agent` header to the node script. I'll add the headers to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Danny! I will ask the company why my original solution is not working. Hopefully I get an answer to share. Have a good one and a happy new year :)